# Magento 2 data migration tool says `Migration completed`, however the data is not migrated

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I want to move to Magento 2. I use the Magento 2 Data Migration Tool to transfer the data from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

The first thing I migrated is settings:

```
sudo php bin/magento migrate:settings -r /path_to_magento_installation/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1.1/config.xml
```

(With the path to my Magento installation instead of `path_to_magento_installation`.)

However, when I go to the Magento 2 backend, I see that my stores and pages (and I think every other setting) is not migrated. It is the same as before using `migrate:settings`.

What went wrong? / What do I have to do?

Comment: did you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue to be caused by me NOT including the "Map Step" in the

> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.0.1/config.xml"
>   file

```
<step title="Map Step">
       <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
       <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
       <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
</step>
```

> remember to also remove the tables you want to copy over to the M2
>   site from the map.xml file. All the basic tables (sales_flat... etc)
>   will be listed in this file in the ignore flag. Remove them for the
>   data to copy over.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing went wrong. Just have to do **reindexing** and clear **cache** with executing the below CLI commands.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If still not work please delete `var/cache` and `var/page_cache` folder.